# How Do I Properly Convert HTML to String?

Tags: iphone, html, string, formatting

I'm a noob to iphone development and I am trying to convert html data into string format.  Currently, I am using stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText to accomplish this, but it ignores the formatting of the HTML. The HTML data I am converting has line breaks, but stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText only removes the HtML tags and doesn't format the resulting string.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

My Code:

```
NSString *temp = [[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"summary"]stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText];
```

HTML data:

```
Holiday Inn<br/>Dedham,MA<br/>Sun May 5th 2013-Sun May 5th 2013<br/>Contact: Harry Tong at 603-978-3459<p><sub><i>-- Delivered by <a href="http://feed43.com/">Feed43</a> service</i></sub></p>
```

Resulting String:

```
Holiday InnDedham,MASun May 5th 2013-Sun May 5th 2013Contact: Harry Tong at 603-978-3459-- Delivered by "http://feed43.com/"Feed43 service
```

I need:

```
Holiday Inn
Dedham,MA
Sun May 5th 2013-Sun May 5th 2013
Contact: Harry Tong at 603-978-3459
-- Delivered by "http://feed43.com/"Feed43 service
```

EDIT

```
NSString *html = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"summary"];
NSString *text = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br/>" withString:@" \n "];
NSString *temp = [text stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just replace the <br/> (and maybe <br> in case of older html) with newline character. Google the newline character in the language you are programming and use a string replace function.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Your answer make a lot of sense but for some reason it doesn't work for me. Please check my edit

Comment: skip the third step (*temp = ...) in *text you already have what you wanted

Answer (score 1):

@Prozi is right.  You can use

```
NSString *text = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br/>" withString:@"\n"];
```

Do that *BEFORE* you remove the html tags.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Your answer make a lot of sense but for some reason it doesn't work for me.  Please check my edit.